# Google Container Builder - image versioning best practice

Tags: google-container-registry

What would be the general guidance on versioning when building a docker image using Google Cloud Builder?

I am specifically interested in the situation when the build is triggered by a code commit. Should the image tag reflect the version (as recommended by Kubernetes API)? If it should, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration, you can specify the image as (for example) `gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image:${REVISION_ID}`, and it will have a tag corresponding to the revision of the commit that triggered the build.

For documentation on the substitution syntax, see https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/build-requests#substitutions